# Eclipse shortcut help (source -> xml & vice versa)

Tags: eclipse, shortcut

I am using Eclipse Juno because of the theme features of this platform. All is well, then I get this difficulty in Android development. When we create a view on the editor there are 2 tabs in the `.xml` file, "Graphical Layout" and "XML source". But after I've change my theme, I can't find these tabs...

Is there a shortcut in order to switch between the two views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to switch to the next page in a multi page editor, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> to switch to the previous page.

Comment: That's exactly what you get with those shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am not focused about the views. What I need is a shortcut to switch from the Graphical Layout to XML view.